# Signal distribution, buffers, rise times and EMC

Tags: signal, emc, buffer, rise-time

I am designing a DSP based audio mixer. There are 4 AD/DA converters (AD1939 and AD1974) and a DSP (OMAP L138), which is on a carrier module. I am distributing the frame clock (48kHz) and the bit clock (~12.3MHz). I have not buffered the TDM digital audio signals as they are point to point.

The frame clock and the bit clock are generated by the master converter and is sent to another slave converter and two inputs in the DSP. The bit clock is sent to two DSP inputs.

I am using a IDT5T30553DCGI to distribute the signals but the rise times in the specs look ridiculously short, with a maximum rise time of 1ns for Cl=15pF. The boards material will be FR4, the lines will be 50Ω and 6-10 cm long. They have been back terminated with a 33Ω series resistor, close to the driver.

The nano second edges are going to create radiation around the 350MHz and multiples. I have been looking for other IC options but their rise time specs are in the same nano second range.

The audio board has also ethernet and all the analogue audio I/O amplifying stages. The mixer board is sitting in a tray with other boards like HD analogue video.

I do not need to pass any EMC compliance tests or similar. Should I worry about EMC aspects in the audio board or adjacent?  Should I worry for those ultra short edges? Am I being too paranoid and it is just fine? Am I creating a problem by distributing signals with those ICs and I should not use anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How slow can the edges be before data becomes unrecognizable? That's probably a good place to start thinking. With a rise time of 1ns and 15pF, the output driving resistance is going to be about 20 ohm. However, you have put 33R in series with the drivers so that should have a marked effect on your rise times - it'll probably increase it to something like 2.6ns and if your clock is 12.3MHz (period of 81ns) a 2.6ns rise and fall time represents 6.4% of the period. You could probably increase rise/fall times to about 20% without much trouble.

This would mean a rise/fall times of about 8ns - this could probably be achieved with 150 ohms in the driver output but, would the receiving DSP chip receive sufficient logic levels?

It's not hard to change these things but will changing them make things worse or better for the adjacent audio board - impossible to say precisely - you're going to just have to try it is my recommendation.

Comment: Someone I asked told me that I should not worry because the rise time of the codec driver would dominate and that the output of the clock buffer will follow the input (as it has a much higher slew rate). 

That does not make too much sense to me as they are CMOS buffers not linear   so, once the input trespasses the MOSFETS threshold, they will switch the output as fast as their current drive capability and load allow.

Comment: One question. When you ask if the receiving DSP woud receive sufficient levels... do you mean voltage levels? I guess I can assume the Zin of any digital input being high enough as to not worry about any series resistance?

Comment: About how slow and how fast can the edges be, it requires a characterisation of the delays in the propagation through the different trace segments and logic that the clock and data traces go across and then check hold and setup times in the receiver are still met, am I right? I do not know how would I do the calculation for the codec as the bitclock (12MHz) is not transmitted but inferred internally with a PLL locked to the transmitted frame clock (48kHz).

Comment: But, finally, in the worst case, if I get any SI/EMC problem, I could slow down the offending line to be as slow as the original unbuffered signal. So, I would be ok, or at least be able to fold back, wouldn't I?

Comment: @jorpese - It's a resistor value and these are easily changed so I would try it. Regarding "sufficient levels" - you are transmitting down a controlled impedance line on your PCB so this, to avoid reflections, might need a termination resistor and could reduce the signal levels more than you think. However, there are ways around this that can usually be put right on the job. I'd make provision for a 47R resistor in series with a 100pF capacitor across the tracks at the receiving end in case transmission line problems are encountered then suck it and see.

Comment: Terminating the line at both ends would half the voltage at the other end; not too good. I do not have the possibility of terminating at the other end, though, as the DSP is on a 3rd party DIMM module. I don't know the module's track impedance either and there would also be reflections on the connector. Would you still put those components close by the connector or just right at the buffer output? Thanks.

Comment: The R and C aren't a full termination - it's a compromise high frequency termination to try and avoid the main problems without affecting the signal amplitude too much. They want to be as close to the receiving end as possible - they do no good at the send end.

Comment: Sorry, I understood something different. R is in series to C and both a shunt to ground, to progressively terminate the line after certain frequency determined by C. 

Unfortunately, it is not that easy. The actual path is: 
codec -> 33R -> 50Ω trace -> clock buffer -> 33Ω -> 50Ω trace-> DIMM connector -> unknown impedance trace -> DSP. 

Would you still put that RC to ground in that case?

Comment: What sort of distances are involved? Even at relatively slow speed (77kbps) over a PCB track I've had problems at 12 inches and found it solved the problem. You are going 200 times faster but your track lengths are going to be much smaller.

Comment: The distances involved are about (layout not yet finished) 

Line 1: codec to DSP = A + B + C

A) Codec to clock buffers: very small <10mm

B) Clock buffer to connector: 3 options: 
- detour bordering the connector to the right pins ~80mm 
- if lucky and can route between the pins ~40mm
- vias + routing on the other side (where could cross a plane slit...) ~40mm (don't like)

C) Module: centre of the DSP (is a BGA) to the connector: ~25mm

Line 2: codec to slave codec: routing allowing, some 50mm

Comment: It's borderline - try and make room for HF terminations where you can dude.

Answer (score 0):

The clock jitter requirements for such ADCs can be extremely demanding (300ps RMS in the case of the AD1939), so I don't think your rise and fall times are excessively short. If you follow good layout practices on a 4-layer or better board (don't split ground planes etc.) and your analog signal path does not allow RF rectification or have excessive bandwidth, I would think you should be okay.

Comment: I use the converter PLL and uses the LRCLK frequency at 48kHz to derive its clock internally. I don't think there could be much problem on that respect.

Comment: About the RF rectification, there is a capacitor in the audio op amps feedback so they have their bandwidth limited. I have 4 layers.

Comment: (Especially) if they are bipolar op-amps, consider a very small capacitor (pF NP0) directly across the input pins.